# How to remove irrelevant data based on content

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, nlp, data-cleaning

I created a program to scrape various news sources for cryptocurrencies such as bitcoin and Ethereum and store the articles in mongodb. The scraper has scraped more than just articles pertaining to crypto and now I’m trying to remove irrelevant articles.

I downloaded the data to a .csv and using pandas to go through and clean the data. The columns are as follows:

```
Index(['_id', 'author', 'title', 'description', 'url', 'urlToImage',
       'publishedAt', 'content', 'summarization', 'source_id']
```

I’m focusing on the content column to try to extract the irrelevant articles. My dilemma is determining the best method to find and remove the irrelevant articles.

My thought process is to find all articles that don’t contain the following strings and delete them:

```
(['cryptocurrency', 'cryptocurrencies', 'bitcoin', 'ethereum']
```

However, I’m unsure if it's the most efficient way to do so. Can anyone recommend ways to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way. Since you have not provided an example of your data. Input is assumed as below (using only 2 columns for demo)

**Input**

```
content             Cost
cryptocurrency      1
cryptocurrencies    2
bitcoin             3
ethereum            4
tesla               5
something           6
else                7
cryptocurrency xyz  8
```

**Code**

```
not_relevant=['cryptocurrency', 'cryptocurrencies', 'bitcoin', 'ethereum']
df[~df.content.str.contains('|'.join(not_relevant), regex=True,case=False)]
```

**Output**

```
content     Cost
tesla       5
something   6
else        7
```